# React reloads upon specific terminal commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, shell, express

Some of this may not be best practice.
I have a react app, connected to an express backend. I am running shell commands from express, so as to use imagemagick and edit image files.

For some odd reason, certain shell commands (run using `shelljs` with `shell.exec()` ), will cause react to reload. I tried taking the commands and running them manually, while my app was running, and react similarly reloaded. What causes this? Is there any way to get around it?

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 18.04 and the regular bash shell.

Example commands:

`convert frontend/webapp/public/images/48.jpg -fill "#000000" -colorize 84 frontend/webapp/public/images/49.jpg`

`curl https://www.healthypawspetinsurance.com/Images/V3/DogAndPuppyInsurance/Dog_CTA_Desktop_HeroImage.jpg > frontend/webapp/public/images/40.jpg`

Comment: Are you changing any javascript/css/image files on disk that would trigger a reload in whatever build tool you're using?

Comment: I used `create-react-app`, that's a good point, I'm not sure which build tool it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are writing the new image to the /public directory, which is most likely watched by the `npm start` command in create-react-app

triggers a reload when a file changes / gets added to that dir

Comment: Thank you, you led me on the right track. Also @bc1105 thank you.